# How to use multiple or statements?

Tags: python

I'm counting the rolls of a dice, and I want my conditions for a 3 of a kind to be that 3 of the 5 rolls are equal, but the other two are not only different from the 3, but different from each other as well.

```
def is_it_three_of_a_kind(self):
    rl = []
    for roll in self.rolls:
        rl.append(roll)
    for i in rl:
        rl.count(i)
        rl.sort()
        if rl.count(i) == 3 and rl[0] != rl[1] or rl[3] != rl[4]:
            return True
```

Using multiple or statements is my best guess but adding both to it makes it check that both rl[0] != rl[1] and rl[3] != rl[4] at the same time. I also just realized that the 3 groupings of the same numbers can be located in the middle so using the train of thought that I was with this code I'd have to add another or statement saying that "rl[0] != rl[4].

Comment: You can write as many `or`s as you like in a row, but you will need brackets around them, like `rl.count(i) == 3 and (rl[0] != rl[1] or rl[3] != rl[4])`, for this logic to work. The `and` operator has higher precedence than `or`.

Comment: You could also use a different approach by doing the math before and using some Python tricks (untested): `len(set(rl)) == 3 and sum(rl.count(r) in (1, 3) for r in set(rl)) == 3`

Answer (score 1):

You will tie yourself in knots trying to list all of the possibilities by referring to each of the five dice by index.  Instead, use a `Counter` object or similar structure to count the quantity of each number in your five dice.

For instance, given a roll of `3 5 3 3 2`, your current method would need to identify

```
rl[0] == rl[2] and rl[2] == rl[4] and \
rl[1] != rl[0] and rl[5] != rl[0] and rl[1] != rl[5]
```

Even if you sort the values, this isn't going to be at all readable for determining the hand.

Instead, reduce this to the counts: `0 1 1 0 3 0`: a 2, a 3, and three 5s.  If you sort that list to get `[3, 1, 1]`, you'll have an easy time identifying your hands:

```
 [5]             five of a kind
 [4, 1]          four of a kind
 [3, 2]          full house
 [3, 1, 1]       three of a kind
 [2, 2, 1]       two pair
 [2, 1, 1, 1]    one pair
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] bust, or a possible straight
```